# Printing only columns in rows that have values from a datagridview

Tags: c#, datagridview

Is it possible to only print the columns in a row in a `DataGridView` that have values and exclude the non empty ones? I'm trying to print the ones and only the ones that have actual values stored in it, but right now it is printing all of them.

Here is a screenshot of the actual print document (saved as a pdf): https://i.stack.imgur.com/OADu1.jpg

I would like to eliminate the rest of the columns that are empty.

Here is the code I have in place to print and the code that fills the data table:

```
private void Printdoc_PrintPage(object sender, System.Drawing.Printing.PrintPageEventArgs e)
    {

        try
        {
            qbcDataGridView.AutoSizeColumnsMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnsMode.AllCells;


            // set the left margin of the document to be printed
            int leftMargin = e.MarginBounds.Left;

            // set the top margin of the document to be printed
            int topMargin = e.MarginBounds.Top;

            // variable to determine if more pages are to be printed
            bool printMore = false;

            // temp width
            int tmpWidth = 0;

            // for the first page to print, set the cell width and header height
            if (firstPage)
            {
                foreach (DataGridViewColumn gridCol in qbcDataGridView.Columns)
                {
                    tmpWidth = (int)(Math.Floor((double)gridCol.Width /
                        totalWidth * totalWidth *
                        ((double)e.MarginBounds.Width / totalWidth)));


                    headerHeight = (int)(e.Graphics.MeasureString(gridCol.HeaderText, gridCol.InheritedStyle.Font, tmpWidth).Height) + 2;

                    // save the width and height of the headers
                    arrayLeftColumns.Add(leftMargin);
                    arrayColWidths.Add(tmpWidth);

                    leftMargin += tmpWidth;
                }
            }


            // loop until all of the grid rows get printed
            while (row <= qbcDataGridView.Rows.Count - 1)
            { 
                DataGridViewRow gridRow = qbcDataGridView.Rows[row];

                // set the cell height
                cellHeight = gridRow.Height + 5;

                int count = 0;

                // check to see if the current page settings allow more rows to print
                if (topMargin + cellHeight >= e.MarginBounds.Height + e.MarginBounds.Top)
                {
                    newPage = true;

                    firstPage = false;

                    printMore = true;

                    break;
                }
                else
                {
                    if (newPage)
                    {
                        // draw the header
                        e.Graphics.DrawString("QBC Directory",
                            new Font(qbcDataGridView.Font, FontStyle.Bold),
                            Brushes.Black, e.MarginBounds.Left,
                            e.MarginBounds.Top - e.Graphics.MeasureString("QBC Directory",
                            new Font(qbcDataGridView.Font, FontStyle.Bold),
                            e.MarginBounds.Width).Height - 13);

                        // set the data (now) and the current time
                        String date = DateTime.Now.ToLongDateString() + " " + DateTime.Now.ToShortTimeString();

                        // draw the date on the print document
                        e.Graphics.DrawString(date,
                            new Font(qbcDataGridView.Font, FontStyle.Bold),
                            Brushes.Black, e.MarginBounds.Left + (e.MarginBounds.Width - e.Graphics.MeasureString(date,
                            new Font(qbcDataGridView.Font, FontStyle.Bold),
                            e.MarginBounds.Width).Width),
                            e.MarginBounds.Top - e.Graphics.MeasureString("QBC Directory", new Font(new Font(qbcDataGridView.Font, FontStyle.Bold),
                            FontStyle.Bold), e.MarginBounds.Width).Height - 13);

                        // draw the column headers
                        topMargin = e.MarginBounds.Top;


                        foreach (DataGridViewColumn gridCol in qbcDataGridView.Columns)
                        {
                            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(gridCol.HeaderText))
                            {
                                // header color
                                e.Graphics.FillRectangle(new SolidBrush(Color.LightGray),
                                    new Rectangle((int)arrayLeftColumns[count], topMargin,
                                    (int)arrayColWidths[count], headerHeight));

                                // header text box
                                e.Graphics.DrawRectangle(Pens.Black,
                                    new Rectangle((int)arrayLeftColumns[count], topMargin,
                                    (int)arrayColWidths[count], headerHeight));

                                // header string
                                e.Graphics.DrawString(gridCol.HeaderText,
                                    gridCol.InheritedStyle.Font, new SolidBrush(gridCol.InheritedStyle.ForeColor),
                                    new RectangleF((int)arrayLeftColumns[count], topMargin, (int)arrayColWidths[count], headerHeight), string_format);
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                break;
                            }

                            count++;
                        }

                        newPage = false;

                        topMargin += headerHeight;
                    }

                    count = 0;

                    // draw the column's contents
                    foreach (DataGridViewCell gridCell in gridRow.Cells)
                    {
                        if (gridCell.Value != null)
                        {
                            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(gridCell.Value.ToString()))
                            {
                                e.Graphics.DrawString(gridCell.Value.ToString(),
                                    gridCell.InheritedStyle.Font, new SolidBrush(gridCell.InheritedStyle.ForeColor),
                                    new RectangleF((int)arrayLeftColumns[count], topMargin, (int)arrayColWidths[count], cellHeight), string_format);
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                break;
                            }
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            break;
                        }

                        // draw the borders for the cells
                        e.Graphics.DrawRectangle(Pens.Black, new Rectangle((int)arrayLeftColumns[count], topMargin, (int)arrayColWidths[count], cellHeight));

                        count++;
                    }
                }

                row++;

                topMargin += cellHeight;

                // if more lines exist, print another page
                if (printMore)
                {
                    e.HasMorePages = true;
                }
                else
                {
                    e.HasMorePages = false;
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
        }

    }
```

and the menu strip item that fills the `DataGridView`:

```
private void MenuViewMembers_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            qbcDataGridView.Font = new Font(qbcDataGridView.Font.FontFamily, 10);

        qbcDataGridView.Location = new Point(30, 100);

        qbcDataGridView.Size = new Size(1500, 500);

        dbConn.Open();

        DataTable dt = new DataTable();


        DbAdapter = new OleDbDataAdapter("select ID, household_head, birthday, phone, email, address, status, spouse, spouse_birthday, spouse_email, anniversary, spouse_status," +
            "child1, child1_birthday, child1_email, child2, child2_birthday, child3_birthday, child4, child4_birthday, child4_email, child5, child5_birthday, child5_email," +
            "child6, child6_birthday, child6_email, child7, child7_birthday, child7_email from members", dbConn);
        DbAdapter.Fill(dt);

        qbcDataGridView.DataSource = dt;


        qbcDataGridView.AutoSizeColumnsMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnsMode.AllCells;

        qbcDataGridView.AutoSizeRowsMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeRowsMode.AllCells;

        qbcDataGridView.DefaultCellStyle.WrapMode = DataGridViewTriState.True;


        dbConn.Close();

        Controls.Add(qbcDataGridView);
    }
```

I think that if only the non-empty values were printed it would format the printed document correctly (see screenshot).

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Update - I got it so where the empty cells are not shown (https://i.stack.imgur.com/TMUKL.jpg) but I guess my other question is how to not have the column headers shown as well if the cells are empty. I updated my code to reflect the changes I made.

Comment: Well, your looping through the rows and printing them individually so yes - check the row has values before printing it.

Comment: exactly how would I check within the datagridview? Sort of confused on what to do.

Comment: Sorry, I misread your question. You would have to make a pass through the rows first, and identify which columns have a value in any of the rows, and keep the column index in a list. Then in your printing code, only print the columns in the list.

Comment: Is there a way to use datagridview to check?

Comment: I don't remember the DataGridView having a `WhichColumnsHaveAValueInAnyOfTheRows` method. It's basically just an adaptation of what you've already got - on the first pass loop through the rows, loop through each column, if there's a value in the column add it to the "valid column" list: on the second pass, loop through the rows, loop through the columns that are in the valid column list, print the values.

Comment: How would I see if there was a value though?

Comment: Well. you already know how to get the value, as in your code - `e.Graphics.DrawString(gridCell.Value.ToString(),` - so you could do a check like `string.IsNullOrEmpty(gridCell.Value.ToString())`

Comment: Ah, thanks, appreciate it

Comment: Just curious, how would I go about not showing column headers if the cell value is empty?

Comment: `foreach (DataGridViewColumn gridCol in qbcDataGridView.Columns.Where(col => validColumnIndexes.Contains(col.Index))) { // print header`

Comment: .Where() isn't available?

Comment: Oh yes, I forgot DataGridView collections are weird. Easiest thing to do then is add `if (!validColumnIndexes.Contains(gridCol.Index)) continue;` as the first line in the loop.

Comment: I'm doing this  `if (!qbcDataGridView.Contains(gridCol.Index) continue;` but I am getting an error that `Argument 1 cannot convert from in to System.Windows.Forms.Control`

Comment: Is `qbcDataGridView` a DataGridView? That would account for the error. Shouldn't you be checking against a list of valid column indexes?

Comment: I just wanted to have it not display column headers if the cell is empty. I have it so far where it doesn't display the cell if no value is in it but can't figure out the header part

Comment: there can be multiple rows with some columns not containing any values or null, for these I want to not show the column headers. I got it working for the cells of the rows, just not the headers because I can't figure it out..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After filling a DataTable with the data, go through the columns and delete the empty.

```
DbAdapter.Fill(dt);

for (int i = dt.Columns.Count - 1; i >= 0; i--)
{
    if (dt.AsEnumerable().All(row => row[i].ToString() == ""))
    {
        dt.Columns.RemoveAt(i);
    }
}

qbcDataGridView.DataSource = dt;
```

Answer (score 0):

Do not mean to provide a duplicate answer but here's an enhancement to Alexander Petrov's answer, in order to handle null data as well, which is possible along with empty strings while reading data from the database table, is as follows:

```
DbAdapter.Fill(dt);

for (int i = dt.Columns.Count - 1; i >= 0; i--)
{
    if (dt.AsEnumerable().All(row => row[i] == null || row => row[i].ToString() == ""))
    {
        dt.Columns.RemoveAt(i);
    }
}

qbcDataGridView.DataSource = dt;
```

Usage of IEnumerable.All Method as [documented](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb548541.aspx).

Comment: if I do that, I am getting an syntax error + indexing error

Comment: Try this exact .All<TSOurce method> : AsEnumerable().All(row => row[i].ToString() == "" || row => row[i] == null) . I just checked on CoderPad and it worked for me. @user2101411 Let me know if this works or not.

Comment: getting a syntax error of ',' expected   

`if (dt.AsEnumerable().All(row => row[i].ToString() == "" || row => row[i] == null))
                        {
                            dt.Columns.RemoveAt(i);
                        }`

Comment: @user2101411, `(row => row[i].ToString() == "" || row => row[i] == null)` should be `(row => row[i] == null || row[i].ToString() == "")`

Comment: @user2101411 how is it possible that it will provide a syntax error in that line saying, syntax error of ',' expected?? Are you sure it's not in some other line??

Answer (score 0):

guys if u have that empty row in datagrid just erase it and it will work fine.
when the loop start and reach the end of the datagrid it will return an exception because the last row has no values